# Reading String for list of Integers separated by spaces

Tags: java, arrays, string

Trying to convert a string, like "21 42 8 7 51" into an Integer array --> [21] [42] [8] etc...

```
    list = "21 42 8";
    String[] splitArray = list.split(" ");
    int[] intArray = new int[splitArray.length]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++){
        intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitArray[i]);
    }


    for (int k = 0; k<intArray.length; k++){
        System.out.println(intArray[k]);
    }
```

The code is what I have written so far, and when I print what is supposed to be my Integer array, it only prints the first index

Comment: `yourString.split(" ")` will return you an array which contains the numbers

Comment: before asking, try to find answer on web.

Comment: You want to create a **nested array** of dimentions `21 x 42 x 8 x 7 x 51` from that `String`?

Comment: It's not very clear what result you want to achieve. Is it the string `"[21] [42] [8] [7] [51]"`, the array `{21, 42, 8, 7, 51}` or, as fabian said, a nested array of dimensions 21 x 42 x 8 x 7 x 51 ? Please rephrase the question so it is made clear, thank you.

Comment: The end result would be an Integer array containing the numbers.

Comment: After your edit, your question is not a question anymore. You have a requirement, you have some code, but what is the problem?

Comment: How do you print the array?

Comment: for (int k = 0; k<intArray.length; k++){

         System.out.println(intArray[k]);
}

The output is only 21

Comment: @DavidKane Cannot reproduce this. for me it prints all 3 ints in their own line...

Answer (score -2):

```
String splitMe= "21 42 8 7 51" ;
String[] values = splitMe.split(" ");
```

Comment: What is wrong with this code?